# Netbeans and Grails - stop server

Tags: grails, netbeans

What is the correct way to stop the web server for Grails in the Netbeans IDE?
After I Run Project (F6), I have been just rebuilding the project to do this. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look under the output tab you can find the task labelled (run-app) and select the Stop icon (a Red Square with a White dot at the center) to stop the application.

Comment: Have no idea why I never saw that. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This is not true. Type in your terminal  "ps aux | grep grails" then you will see a number associated with the app and type "kill -9 (then the number)" and it will stop all process

Answer (score 0):

There is no special Grails command to stop a running server, so just use whatever Netbeans provides to stop a project that was started from inside the IDE

Comment: The only thing I have found so far is recompiling the project seems to work. But this does seem like overkill just to kill the webapp.